# Can you apply to internships that ask you when you are expected to graduate even though you graduated?

Tags: job-search, resume, internship, education, computer-science

I recently graduated in 2022 with a bachelor's degree related to a science field, and I got a certificate in Computer Science during the summer of 2022. As I am currently job searching for entry-level jobs and internships relating to coding, I noticed that most of them say that the qualification for applying are students that are pursuing a bachelor's degree who will be junior or senior in Fall 2023. **Can I still apply even though I graduated in 2022?** I have no job experience in coding, so I believe that an internship is the best way to gain some experience for a person who is changing career paths.

**Are they only looking for applicants that are in college? Is it bad to apply for an internship after you graduate?**

Comment: VTC - my initial thought is if the internship specifically states it is for studying students, then no - however the answer to the question will lie with the specific company policy/HR Policy - to which we cannot comment on, hence VTC.

Comment: In some countries companies may get gov’t issued grants or pay lower taxes and/or social security for such employee provided one still studies. Also young age may qualify. Check your local rules, but be wary you may be at a disadvantage.

Comment: In France I don't think it's legally permitted to have an internship without being affiliated to a school, so it's really country specific.

Comment: It usually doesn't make any sense for graduates to apply to internships.  Most companies have the same interview/assessment process and measure against the same skill/experience criteria for evaluating intern candidates as they would when seeking candidates into permanent graduate/apprentice/junior employees.  The only real difference being employment terms;  i.e. a short, fixed-term contract with a built-in end date, and most likely a much lower salary.    The best thing to do is contact whoever handles this company's recruitment and explain your career switching intentions to them.

Answer (score 4):

I'd advise you to call/email the HR department of the most attractive companies and describe your position and see what they say about it.

It's quite possible they'll be able to accept a candidate with your situation, it's also possible that they only want candidates who are currently studying.

Answer (score 0):

If in doubt I'd just apply anyway. Nothing to lose and best case scenario someone notices you and you get what you want.

For the bits about prior to graduation I'd just put N/A (not applicable) or 'Already graduated'.